# Как сделать переключатель между значениями массива?

Tags: java, массивы, switch, условия

Есть несколько пар логически взаимосвязанных сущностей:
`а` `b`, `c` `d`, `e` `f` итд.
Есть пачка условий, по которым они переключаются по правилу:
Если сущность `obj` равна первому значению в первой паре (`а`), она становится равна второму значению в паре (`b`).
Если сущность `obj` равна второму значению во второй паре (`d`), она становится равна первому значению в паре (`c`). Итд.

```
if (obj == a)){
    obj  = b; return obj;
}
if (obj == c)){
    obj  = d; return obj;
}
```

итд, плюс в обратном порядке тоже:

```
if (obj == b)){
    obj  = a; return obj;
}
if (obj == d)){
    obj  = c; return obj;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста способ, с помощью которого можно избавиться от этой прорвы условий, чтобы переключаться между парами значений.

Comment: `return (obj == a ? b : a);`

Comment: @splash58 вариант хороший, сокращает вдвое количество условий. Только надо перечислить все возможные пары руками.

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое сущности в вашем понимании. Есть такое замечательная штука, как полиморфизм. Может создать им общего предка, определить в нем метод, а потом вызывать его, как и принято делать в ООП

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Спасибо за ответы!**
Сам я сделал так.
-в интерфейсе добавил константу двумерный массив с парами:

```
Point[][] DIRECTION_PAIRS = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
```

-добавил метод, осуществляющий переключение между парами.
Цикл вытаскивает подряд пару `{c1, c2}` из объявленной константы `DIRECTION_PAIRS`.
Если `i` нечетное, менять первый элемент на второй. Если `i` четное - второй на первый.

```
public Point translateDirectionPoint(int i, Point p){
        for (Point[] pair : DIRECTION_PAIRS) {
            if (i%2 == 1 && p.equals(pair[0])){
                p = pair[1];
                break;
            }
            if (i%2 == 0 && p.equals(pair[1])){
                p = pair[0];
                break;
            }
        }
        return p;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, через `Map`

```
Map<Object, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put(a, b);
data.put(b, a);
data.put(c, d);
data.put(d, c);
.........
if (data.containsKey(obj))
  return data.get(obj);
```

Если же у Вас требование для нечетного элемента возвращать следующий элемент, а для четного предыдущий, то еще проще

```
ArrayList<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add(a);
data.add(b);
data.add(c);
data.add(d);
........
int idx = data.indexOf(obj);
if (idx == -1) {
  .......
} else {
  if (idx % 2 == 0)
    idx++;
  else
    idx--;
  if (idx >= data.size()))
    idx = 0;
  else if (idx < 0)
    idx = data.size() - 1;
  return data.get(idx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
public Object check(Object o, Object...args) {
    if (args.length %2 != 0) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Arguments counts must be odd");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (o.equals(args[i]))
            return args[i + (i%2==0 ? 1 : -1) ];
    }
    return null; //not found
}
```

Вызывать так:

```
check(7, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```